# need display 2 hour scale in jqtimeline

Tags: jquery, timeline

I am using jqtimeline.js its working fine for me but I am facing problem to display only 2 hour scale and I don’t want to display any date corresponding hour .i just want display hour to hour (for example 0min,30min…).

Can anyone suggest me how I can display only hour scale.

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow. For us to help you better try showing us some sample code you have tried.

Comment: you can refer this url..i am using that ..http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Lightweight-jQuery-Timeline-Plugin-jqtimeline.html

Comment: can you plz help me how i can do ?..is it possible or not

Comment: We generally try to edit with your fiddle, try creating a working code here: http://jsfiddle.com , then we may be able to play around with the code and tell you if any solution is found.